# What is transactional memory and what would it change in C++ programming (C++20)

Tags: c++, c++20, transactional-memory

One of the proposed features for C++20 is transactional memory.

What is it? Is it going to simplify multithreaded programming in C++?

Comment: Proposed for C++20? Didn't they agree to keep it as a TS as long as they have sufficient user experience to propose it as a feature for the IS?

Comment: I don't know much about [tag:c++], but [tag:transactional-memory] is pretty much exactly what it says on the tin: it is memory that is transactional, exactly like in a database. Memory can only be modified inside a transaction, and if two threads modify the same piece of memory at the same time, (at least one of) the transaction(s) is/are rolled back and retried.

Comment: I tried to summaries TM a bit as a response to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829838/what-is-transactional-memory-in-comparison-to-actor-model-and-locks. Have a look and let me know if you need further info.